# access call_history.db in ios 5.0 or ios 6.0

Tags: iphone, database

I know that what i am asking and it is not possible. But I have seen this till ios 4.3. SO I want to access call_history database for application. My requirement is that i want pick up last dialled or incoming number and save in address book if not exist.

So if anybody have any information then share with me.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Apple probably tightened up the sandboxing rules. They do this from time to time - I noticed in iOS 5 I lose the ability to read or write certain directories that we weren't supposed to touch.

Answer (score 0):

You can get last dialled number using following code snippet:

```
NSString *path = @"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mobilephone.plist";
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSString *lastDialed = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dict valueForKey:@"DialerSavedNumber"]];
```

Comment: Looks like apple tightened the sandbox further in 6.0.